# ValueError and ImportError inside package directory when import variable from init file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a directory application in which I have two files. **init**.py and routes.py. I have set a variable in **init**.py. while I am one directory below package directory application ,  I am able to import the variable.

```
>>> from application  import hello_api_blueprint 
>>> hello_api_blueprint 
<flask.blueprints.Blueprint object at 0x7f4d6869da10>
```

But when I am inside package directory - application I am not able to import with multiple way

```
>>> from application  import hello_api_blueprint
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named application
>>> from .  import hello_api_blueprint
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

How can I import this variable when I am inside the directory.

Comment: Just directly use 
`import hello_api_blueprint`

Comment: I again get  ImportError

Comment: Do you have `__init__.py` file inside application

Comment: Which cmd are you using to run this code?

Comment: Yes I have init file inside application and I am doing with relative and absolute import as shown in original post.

Comment: How are you running your code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/how-to-fix-attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py